# Angular2+ caching practices

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm experimenting with Angular 2 and caching of values received from backend services. I've noticed that I came to the following pattern - using `BehaviorSubject` with undefined initial value and filter it to postpone display of controls dependent on values received from backend.

```
private _lazyValue: BehaviorSubject<ILazyValue> =
    new BehaviorSubject<ILazyValue>(undefined);

get lazyValue(): Observable<ILazyValue> {
  return this._lazyValue.filter(val => val !== undefined);
}
```

Inside template:

```
<div *ngIf="lazyValue | async; else nolv; let lv">
  <app-some-control [lazy_value]="lv"></app-some-control>
</div>
<ng-template #nolv>
  <span>Loading...</span>
</ng-template>
```

**Question:** are there any shortcuts for this somewhat fishy expression:

```
this._lazyValue.filter(val => val !== undefined)
```

Do I misuse `BehaviorSubject` somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
this._lazyValue.filter(Boolean)
```

That looks more clean.

But it seems you don't need to be using `BehaviorSubject` at all and use `ReplaySubject(1)` instead.